# TFS2012 User Storys Tasks with different iteration paths

Tags: tfs, iteration, task, agile, user-stories

In my Company we are using Team Foundation Server 2012 and Agile as Project Template. We are still learning how the Board and the Backlog show Tasks within User Stories and I realized that "Orphan" Tasks are not shown in these cases...
I made an query to solve the problem about the "Orphan" tasks but I realized that the same issue is happening when a User Story and a Task have, for some reason (maybe someone assign it to a User Story after creating it), a different iteration path... the tasks are not shown in the Backlog or Board.
Is there an automatic way to make tasks having the same iteration path as their parents? How can I make a query to show tasks whose User Stories have a different iteration path as them?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. After more researching I have realized about two thing:
- It is not needed to do this in order to show the Tasks in the Board/Backlog because, if the User Story contains tasks that are defined in different iterations, the User Story will be shown in the different iterations, repeated, but only with the tasks belonging to the iteration.
- If someone still wants to create the query, maybe to reunite User Stories, the solution is creating a new Query of the type Work Items and Direct Links and change the following parameters:
  * In Filters for top level work item Add a new clause And Iteration Path = IterationA
  * In Filters for linked work items Add a new clause And Iteration Path <> IterationA
  * In Filter options Types of links select Return selected link types and check Child and Parent.
Unfortunately there is no way, so far I know, to do it automatically for all iterations so you have to do a Query of this type for all iterations.

Comment: While I don't think you can do it automatically for all iterations, you can at least use @CurrentIteration for the current iteration.  It's better than nothing.